# Event firing Multiple times in Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I Have created an Event from the Tag Manager. When I check by clicking it works fine but the problem is, this event is firirng number of times I have clicked on it. Example if I click for 10 times Event is firing 10 times. I want only one click to be recorded as I don't need duplicates can anyone help me in this regards

Comment: The event will be fired multiple times, but you can limit your tags to run once per page.

Comment: Can you please tell me the procedure

Answer (score 5):

For any type of tag, you can set this behavior within the Advanced Settings block of the tag setup screen:
[image]

If you choose 'Once per page' for the 'Tag firing options', the event will be fired multiple times, but this tags will run only once per page.